# laravel DB::raw SELECT WITH WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: php, laravel

i have order table that a user may have many rows in it so i want to get the status of the latest order by the current user

I want to get the status of the row that has the max id where user id is equal to the current auth user id,

table structure:

order(id,user_id,item_id,....,status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$userId = Auth::user()->id;
DB::table('order')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->select('status')->where('user_id',$userId)->get();
```

Comment: this works but  when i try {{ $status }} in the view it gives me an error and when i print_r the status it gives me (stdClass Object ( [status] => 3 ) i want the number only

Comment: how you are passing data to view ?

Comment: ->with('status',$status)

Comment: i dont get any errors just the page breaks down i guess they stopped debugging in the site

Comment: Try using `first()` instead of `get()` and in view `{{ $status }}`

Comment: im using first Lol, it's ur solution remember?

Comment: stdClass Object ( [status] => 3 )

Comment: `{{ $status -> status }}`

Comment: This returns an object. And to access an object property syntax is `$obj -> key`. $status is the object. and status is a key within. This is why I never name objects and keys same :P

Comment: thanx sir you saved my day

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this:

```
$currentUserId = Auth::user()->id;

DB::table('order')->select('status')->where('user_id',$currentUserId)->orderBy('created_at','desc')->get();
```

Hope this work for you

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Query**

SELECT o.status FROM order AS o WHERE o.user_id=? ORDER BY o.id DESC LIMIT 0,1;

**Laravel**

```
$user_id = 123;
DB::table('order')
    ->select(DB::raw('status'))
    ->where('user_id', '=', $user_id)
    ->orderby('id', 'DESC')
    ->first();
```